# Change the identity from Azure AD to identity of application and return new token

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

I use this code to change the identity coming from Azure AD in an identity usable by my application, then i generate a token for this identity and return it in the response headers.

Is this secure? and is it the good way? In particular, call the SignIn method of the AuthenticationManager and handle this in a middleware to generate a token.

**Environment**

Asp.net-WebAPI with OWIN

**Code in startup.cs**

1. Add Azure AD middleware
2. On validate identity, create a custom identity for the authentified user and signin with this identity

   ```
   app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
   {
       Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
       Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
       Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
       {
           OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
           {
               if(!context.IsValidated)
                   return;

               var userManager = context.OwinContext.Get<UserManager>();
               string email =    context.Ticket.Identity.GetClaimValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email);
               User user = userManager.GetByEmail(email);

               if(user == null)
               {
                   // Create user
               }

               // Create custom identity
               ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(AuthenticationTypes.My);
               identity.AddClaim(new Claim(My.ClaimTypes.UserId, user.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

               // Signal to middleware to treat my custom identity
               context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(identity);

               // validate the identity
               AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, null); 
               context.Validated(ticket);
           }
       }
   });
   ```
3. Add a custom middleware to handle the signin with my custom identity to create a new token and return it to browser

   ```
   app.Use((context, next) =>
   {
       if(context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant == null)
           return next();
       if(context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.AuthenticationType != AuthenticationTypes.My)
           return next();

       // Create a token with the custom identity
       AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity, null);
       IDataProtector dataProtecter = app.CreateDataProtector(typeof(OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware).Namespace, "Access_Token", "v1");
       TicketDataFormat ticketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtecter);
       string token = ticketDataFormat.Protect(ticket);
       context.Response.Headers.Add("access_token", new string[] { token });
       return next();
   });
   ```
4. Add a OAuth bearer authentication middleware to handle my custom token:

   ```
   app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
   {
       TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
       AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
       AccessTokenFormat = null,
   });
   ```